# NSDateFormatter is adding AM/PM when date format doesn't specify it

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have simple code that transforms a date into a string:

```objc
+ (NSString *)dateStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

I would expect a string like:

```
2020-10-19T11:55:29Z
```

But instead it is outputting a string like this:

```
2020-10-19T12:38:06 p.m.Z
```

Note the "p.m." in the output. I am not using the "a" date format character, so I would not expect to see AM or PM.

When I run the code in the simulator, it produces the correct result. When I run it on a physical iPad running iPadOS 14.0.1 it produces the incorrect result.

I have noticed that forcing the locale with this fixes the issue:

```objc
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

But, I'm not sure if that is the correct approach, as this seems like a bug.

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening?

Comment: It's because of the default local of the `NSDateFormatter`. But if you look at "am/mp" + NSDateFormatter + en_us_posix", you'll find plenty of "issues". So yes, you need to use the en_us_posix. You iPad, as I guess use the AM/MP system in its settings, no? But you might be interested in the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there some reason why this wasn't an issue prior to iPadOS 14? We have never seen this before 14.x.

Comment: @Larme if you wanted to submit your comment as the answer, I would mark it as accepted. Your comment helped. Thank you!